# What font is used for ASL STAR's logo?

Tags: font-identification

I'm currently working on a logo redesign project, this is part of what the client has. I need to make this into a vector logo but they also wanted to know actual font for this.

I've already tried:

- WhatTheFont!
- Identifont
- Serif Font Identification Guide
- What Font is

Been trying to find this font for a little while now, any help is welcome, thanks!

[image: ASL Star logo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be [AnotherLine](http://www.dafont.com/anotherline.font?text=ASL%20STAR) by [Xerographer Fonts](http://xerographer.blogspot.com/). Usually if a font is not recognized by the automatic services then it can be found on dafont. In this case, it was appropriately listed under the [Techno > Square category](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=301).

I suspect a pseudo-bold was added since dafont does not have any weights available besides Regular.

[image: ASL Star Logo recreated]

It is worth noting that the author asks to be contacted for commercial licensing.

Comment: Yup, I got you on that part re: commercial licensing :)